# Django save() behavior with autocommit transactions

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, innodb

I have a following setup:

- Several data processing workers get configuration from django view `get_conf()` by http.
- Configuration is stored in django model using MySQL / InnoDB backend
- Configuration model has overridden `save()` method which tells workers to reload configuration

I have noticed that sometimes the workers do not receive the changed configuration correctly. In particular, when the conf reload time was shorter than usual, the workers got "old" configuration from `get_conf()` (missing the most recent change). The transaction model used in Django is the default autocommit.

I have come up with the following possible scenario that could cause the behavior:

1. New configuration is saved
2. `save()` returns but MySQL / InnoDB is still processing the (auto)commit
3. Workers are booted and make http request for new configuration
4. MySQL (auto)commit finishes

Is the step 2 in the above scenario possible? That is, can django model `save()` return before the data is actually committed in the DB if the autocommit transactional method is being used? Or, to go one layer down, can MySQL autocommitting `INSERT` or `UPDATE` operation finish before the commit is complete (update / insert visible to other transactions)?

Comment: Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM for your engine?

Comment: InnoDB. The DB is running on Amazon RDS with default configuration. There are some large tables, but the table(s) related to this problem are small (on the order of 128kb or so)

Comment: Can you turn off autocommit just for this case?

Comment: Can you provide a little more info on the mechanics of "tells workers to reload"? If the workers are in a different process (e.g., if you are notifying via Celery or Python-RQ), then yes - your step 2 can/will almost definitely happen.

Comment: Workers are running in different processes, in different EC2 instances. They are ordered to reload by making a ssh connection (through paramiko) to the instance(s) and sending the workers a unix signal telling them to reload configuration. The signaling is done after superclass save().

Comment: Modifying my comment, a little: on databases I'm familiar with (PostgreSQL, MSSQL, Oracle) commits of any kind (auto or manual) block until complete. So, the flow you describe should work, since the db call happens before the signal. If the entire view were transactional (e.g., `ATOMIC_REQUESTS=True`, then you could have a race where the other process tries to load before the commit occurs). Considering the workers get their conf via an HTTP connection, is there caching occurring at any layer?

Comment: Have you tried to test this through curl or wget disabling caching (for simulating worker http get)? Caching could happen in different places and I bet for this, maybe also be a template caching in Django.

Comment: @bimsapi Thanks for the hint about caching. We are not explicitly doing any caching in Django or nginx, but I'll try to find out if there is something along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Object may be getting dirty, please try  refresh object after save.

> obj.save()
>
> obj.refresh_from_db()

reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like a race condition.

The scenario you describe should never happen if there's only one script and one database. When you save(), the method doesn't return until the data is actually commited to the database.

If however you're using a master/slave configuration, you could be the victim of the replication delay: if you write on the master but read on the slaves, then it is entirely possible that your script doesn't wait long enough for the replication to occur, and you read the old conf from the slave before it had the opportunity to replicate the master.

Such a configuration can be set up in django using database routers, or it can be done on the DB side by using a DB proxy. Check that out.